# Confused regarding split in Java

Tags: java, split

I am trying to take a text from a file,  and take the a's and b's out using split function.

```
        String inStr = in.readLine();
```

// for example "a1a1a1a1b"

```
        String lettersStr = letters.readLine();
```

// for example "ab"

Then i'm doing this trying to split all the letters i want.
Why is this not working?

```
        String outFinal = "\"\\\\s*["+ lettersStr +"]\\\\s*\"";
        String[] inSplit = inStr.split(outFinal);
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is

```
        inStr.split("\\s*[ab]\\s*"));
```

Which works fine but the problem is that since i'm using a BufferedReader (fileread) the letters to cut out keep changing, hence why i can't just use the line above.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`String outFinal = "\"\\\\s*["+ lettersStr +"]\\\\s*\"";`

to

`String outFinal = "\\s*["+ lettersStr +"]\\s*";`

Comment: Thank you! I now realize that by doing so and calling outFinal as parameter it automatically adds the required "s

Comment: You are welcome. Hope I have addressed your question.